# Ninject Conventions with multiple Froms

Tags: ninject, ninject-3

I have some code in a NinjectModule that sets up Mock bindings for all interfaces in multiple assemblies.  Ninject 2 allowed me to call the `From()` methods multiple times inside the `Scan` lambda:

```
Kernel.Scan(scanner =>
{
    string first = "MyAssembly";
    Assembly second = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly");
    scanner.From(first);
    scanner.From(second);
    scanner.BindWith<MockBindingGenerator>();
});
```

The new way in Ninject 3 doesn't allow chained `From()` calls, as far as I can tell.  This is the best equivalent I could come up with:

```
string first = "MyAssembly";
Assembly second = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly");

Kernel.Bind(x => x
    .From(first)
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .BindWith<MockBindingGenerator>());

Kernel.Bind(x => x
    .From(second)
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .BindWith<MockBindingGenerator>());
```

My new code breaks* when a single assembly is loaded multiple times, as seen above.  Note that the `first` and `second` variables are of different types, so I can't simply combine them into a single call.  My real production code has the same issue, but of course I'm not simply hard-coding the same assembly name twice.

So, how can I rewrite the above so that I can combine multiple `From()` calls and only call `BindWith<>` once?

#### Edit

* The binding code itself executes just fine.  The exception occurs when I try to get an instance of an interface that exists in an assembly that was bound twice.

Answer (score 3):

Did you see the `Join` syntax at the bottom of https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/wiki/Overview ? I imagine it's what you're after...

(For bonus points: If you saw the docs and it just didn't jump out, can you suggest whether you reckon it'd best be separated into a new Wiki page or do you have other ideas? If you're just consuming it from IntelliSense, can you suggest a way you might have discovered it more easily?

EDIT: On reflection, I'm guessing you didn't see it due to the fact that the `.Join` doesn't become available until you've done the `.Select...` bit. (BTW my interest in this is driven by the fact that I did some editing in the wiki; feel free to edit in anything you've learned from this encounter in there too.))

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by creating a list of all assembly names:

```
string first = "MyAssembly";                    // .From("MyAssembly")
Assembly second = Assembly.Load("MyAssembly");  // .From(Assembly.Load("MyAssembly"))
Type third = typeof(Foo);                       // .FromAssemblyContaining<Foo>

Kernel.Bind(x => x
    .From(new [] { first, second.FullName, third.Assembly.FullName })
    .SelectAllInterfaces()
    .BindWith<MockBindingGenerator>());
```